# How to minimise Firebase Function Latency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

As per the documentation, Firebase Functions are currently supported for 4 regions only - “us-central1”, “us-east1", “europe-west1”, “asia-northeast1"

That means locations further away would incur more latency, and often that translates to lower performance.

How can this limitation be worked around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Choosing a location that is closest to you**. You can set up test cloud functions in different regions, and test the round-trip latency. Only you can discover the specifics about your location.

2) Focus your **software architecture** on infrastructure that is locally available.

Use the client-side Firestore library directly as much as possible. It supports offline data, queueing data to send out later if you don't have internet, and caching read data locally - you can't get faster latency than that! So make sure you use Firestore for CRUD operations.

3) Architect to use CloudFunctions for **batch and background processesing**. If any business-logic processing is required, write the data to Firestore (using client libraries), and have a FF trigger to do some processing upon the write data-event. Have that trigger update that record with the additional processing, and state. I believe that if you're using the client-side libraries there is a way to have the updated data automatically pushed back to the client-side. (edited)

You also have the bonus benefit of being able to control authorisation with Firestore Auth, where Functions don't have an admin-level authorisation control.

4) **Reduce chatter** - minimising the amount of CloudFunction calls overall, and ensuring your CloudFunctions themselves do more in one go and return more complete data in one go.